# Transfer recording from 4 Track Tascam 246 from another model possible?

Tags: recording, tascam, transfer, 4-track

I've been searching the net to see if it's possible to transfer some old recordings I did from a Tascam 246 4 Track recorder from a different 4 track unit?

One hurdle is that the speed was not regular speed. Would this be possible, say on a different unit from Tascam? I mean I would imagine that maybe if I were to do it from a Fostex, that it might not be possible.

I just want to transfer it to my new digital mixer so I can go back and make some mixes. Does anyone know? Thanks in advance........

Comment: Which model will you be using?

Comment: @MichaelHansenBuur, not really sure. I had none in mind, but I just wanted to see if there is any other model that I can find. I've seen newer models on sale, so it's just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed may vary (and actually you may even see differences between units of the same model). If you know the tuning, chords etc you can always go through a computer and resample if you want pitch to be perfect.

Comment: That's interesting, but it makes sense that through the different unit same model there would be differences. That of course, as you said, wouldn't be much concern to me as I can tweak or adjust the tuning on the instruments. I will have to experiment then.

Comment: I ended up buying a Tascam 464. I'm waiting for it to arrive. We shall see how this goes. Manual seems to imply the speeds are the same and compatible.

Comment: So I ended up buying a Tascam Portastudio 464. I was fortunate to be so picky about the tapes I bought. I bought the real expensive ones that are apparently able to withstand heat (according to the case). Awesome stuff, They sound perfect. There was maybe 2 or 3 tapes that had lower quality tapes and those are just a little bit off. It pays to pay. Thanks for your feedback. I almost spent a fortune instead of buying this unit.

Comment: Cool - glad it turned out well. Pitch is ok too?

Comment: Pitch is good on all of them except for the 2-3 that I used lower quality tapes. On those it sounds a little off. I will have to adjust, but it's not that bad actually. Analog sounds so different, I missed that sound.